# array of custom type arrays

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have defined a new class type called `Hotspot`. I need 2 dynamic array of Hotspot (I used List) and a third one that allow me to "switch" between them. Here my code:

```
List<Hotspot> items = new List<Hotspot>();
List<Hotspot> locations = new List<Hotspot>();

Hotspot[][] arrays = new Hotspot[][]{items, locations};
```

but `arrays` doesn't work. I just need it so I can easily access to `items/locations` array.

In F# I did it in this way:

```
let mutable items = new ResizeArray<Hotspot>()
let mutable locations = new ResizeArray<Hotspot>()

let arrays = [|items; locations|]
```

but I can't do the same thing in C#. Some help?

Comment: It doesn't work because a List<Hotspot> is not the same as a Hotspot.  In other words, you declare `arrays` to be a 2d array of Hotspots, yet you try filling it with two Lists.  With static typing, that can't happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Hotspot>[] arrays = new List<Hotspot>[]{items, locations};
```

Answer (score 3):

`items` and `locations` are declared (and instantiated) as lists.  Lists are not arrays and you're trying to assign them as arrays.  Convert them to arrays or don't use arrays at all but a list instead.

```
Hotspot[][] arrays = new Hotspot[][]{ items.ToArray(), locations.ToArray() };
//or
List<Hotspot>[] lists = new[] { items, locations };
```

p.s., The F# `ResizeArray<T>` is essentially an alias to the .NET `List<T>`.  So in effect, the `arrays` variable in your F# example is equivalent to `lists` in my example above, you created an array of lists.

Comment: The latter is much cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: I don't know why there was problems about the position of "arrays" declaration. Done within Form_Load() and it works. It makes no sense for me...